# "Could not send (POST) Request" with postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, postman

I want to test my POST API with POSTMAN.
I already know, the POST-Request is working because it creates a new entry in the database.
So, I'm probably using Postman wrong.
Can someone please help me out?

This is the API

```
/**
 * @name postSearchOffer
 * @desc Will create an entry in the database in the table angebot_von_student
 * @param {*} req 
 * @param {*} res 
 */
const postSearchOffer = (req, res) => {
    try {
        date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace('T', ' ');
        var userID = req.params.id;
        var title = req.body.title;
        var description = req.body.desc;
        var cat = parseInt(req.body.category);
        var created_date = date;
        var updated_date = date;
        var imgID = parseInt(req.body.option);
        var price = parseInt(req.body.price);

        Offer.create({
          UserID: userID, 
          Titel: title,
          Beschreibung: description,
          KategorieID: cat,
          erstellt_am: created_date,
          update_am: updated_date,
          AnzeigebildID: imgID,
          Preis: price
        });
        res.status(200).redirect(url_frontend + "/search"); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
      }
}
```

This is my postman request
[image: postman req]

and this is the postman header
[image: postman header]